# How to add an EventSource details page for Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'd like to add a EventSource detail page to Adam Shaw's [Fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/). A use case for this page is that the user wants to change the URL of the source or change the color of the events belonging to this source. For now I am blocked by the fact that I don't know exactly how to retrieve the source object. Part of the problem is that as far as I know, sources do not have an ID.

Which is the proper function in which I should inject the EventSourceID into the source object?
Should this function be something similar to the addEventSource from $ROOT/src/common/Views.js?

UPDATE: I changed the text in question the source to EventSource, to make it clear. Also now I have one solution in my mind, let me know if it's intrusive:

1. make sure each source object has an ID property set. This could be done by adding a source normalizer function to fc.sourceNormalizers array.
2. create retrieveEventSource which takes an EventSourceID as an argument and returns the source. The implementation this would be similar to _addEventSource.

UPDATE: Already found a problem, function retrieveEventSource is private and I don't know how to expose it to the world outside FullCalendar. Also, I have no idea yet on how to implement the update function that should redraw /AND/OR/ refetch the events, after the source details have changed.

Comment: Source object of a calendar event?

Comment: Yes, I mean eventSource/s, the sources for calendar events. I also updated the text of the question to make sure it's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you're the one that populates the calendar event data in the first place just use that data on the new page.

```
events: function (start, end, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: "json-events.php",
        success: function (data) {
            callback([event0,event1,event2,.....])
        },
        dataType: /* xml, json, script, or html */
    });
    ...
```

Just get the data on the other page outside the calendars api